# CloudFlare Error 521 only if setting ssl mode to full

Tags: ssl, server, cloudflare, vps

I'm using CloudFlare SSL. when I set SSL to **flexible** everything works fine.

But if I use **full** SSL mode this error occurs instantly:

[image]

Note that I set the certificate and the key in my cpanel ssl section and I think everything is done ok.

Why this is happening and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. All you have to remember is:

1. Flexible - there should be no SSL installed for that domain on the server ( no VHOST for port 443 either ).
2. Full - there should be an SSL installed for that domain, but it does not have to be a valid one ( you can use a self-signed or expired SSL ).
3. Full Strict - there should be a VALID SSL installed for that domain on the server ( it has to be absolutely a valid and active SSL ).

So, depending on the SSL you have on your domain server, just set the Cloudflare SSL to one of the above options. If you believe that everything is okay and you still get an issue, I would suggest reaching your web host to check that further for you.